# Setting subclass primary key as auto_increment using JPA 2 annotations

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to generate a database schema for my project using hbm2ddl. I'm using JPA 2 annotations to specify how the schema should look like. Right now I'm having some issues with inherited id's.

I have an abstract super class, let's call it AbstractSuperClass, which looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractSuperClass {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
    }
    ...
}
```

I've set the id to be an auto generated value which translates to SQL's auto_increment constraint. However when I look at the generated script, I don't see the id columns of the subclass tables to have the auto_increment in them.

Anyone has an idea how I could get that? Of course I could manually specify it but as much as possible I want it automated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not supported, as mentioned in the Reference Documentation in the section about inheritance mapping:

> #### [2.2.4.1. Table per class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1191)
>
> This strategy has many drawbacks (esp.
>   with polymorphic queries and
>   associations) explained in the JPA
>   spec, the Hibernate reference
>   documentation, Hibernate in Action,
>   and many other places. Hibernate work
>   around most of them implementing this
>   strategy using SQL UNION queries. It
>   is commonly used for the top level of
>   an inheritance hierarchy:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
> public class Flight implements Serializable { ... }
> ```
>
> This strategy supports one-to-many
>   associations provided that they are
>   bidirectional. **This strategy does
>   not support the IDENTITY generator
>   strategy: the id has to be shared
>   across several tables. Consequently,
>   when using this strategy, you should
>   not use AUTO nor IDENTITY**.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to answers but thanks; I missed that part. I wonder why that strategy won't support AUTO though. I don't get the part saying, > the id has to be shared across several
> tables Why does it have to be shared when each class has its own table?

Comment: You should be able to comment answers and you didn't which is why I didn't notice your question :) Suppose you have two subclasses B and C of A and you want to find a A by id (e.g. 1). If both B and C have a record with id=1, who is the "right" one? There is no answer. That's why values of the the identity column in each table must be mutually exclusive when using a "table per class" strategy, which is why IDENTITY (and also AUTO which could default to IDENTITY) is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Note that GenerationType.AUTO means that it's up to the persistence provider to select a generation strategy, have you tried a more specific value?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the guy is asking how to auto_increment he's id columns using JPA 2 annotations.

Dude, just declare strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY on your @GeneratedValue annotation.
e.g. :

```
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

protected  long  anyIdhere;

Hope this will help you.